# An urn has 4 balls of 4 different colours Red,Blue,Green,Yellow.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

> An urn has $4$ balls of $4$ different colours; red, blue, green, and
>   yellow. I pick one ball at random at first and if it is red, I paint
>   it blue and return it to the urn. If it is blue, I paint it green. If
>   it is green, I paint it yellow. If it is yellow, I paint it red. What
>   is the expected number of trials to get all $4$ balls of the same
>   colour?

Reminder:

$$\color{red}{red}\to \color{blue}{blue}$$
$$\color{blue}{blue}\to \color{green}{green}$$
$$\color{green}{green}\to \color{yellow}{yellow}$$
$$\color{yellow}{yellow}\to \color{red}{red}$$

I am really stuck with this problem. Help!

Comment: *Where* are you stuck with this problem?  What have you tried?  How far have you gotten? What is the difficulty you encountered?

Comment: For one, two, and three colors, the expected times are $0$, $1$, and $9$ (the first two are deterministic).  I'm working on four colors; the state diagram has ten states, so it may take a bit...

Comment: OK, I've finished and added my answer.  I *think* it's correct, though there seems to be some minor discrepancy between my result and that of a commenter on my answer.

Comment: Update: Discrepancy resolved!

Answer (score 4):

This problem is equivalent to one in which there are four people in four rooms that are joined cyclically by corridors.  Initially, each room has one of the four people, and at each turn, one person (*not* one room) is chosen at random, and this person moves counterclockwise.  How long before they end up in the same room?

One can define a Markov chain that records the relative position of the four people.  It will be easier to explain this first for the case of three people.  There are only four possible states:

- One person in each of the three rooms, which we denote $111$.
- Two people in one room, and one person in the next room, which we denote $21$.
- One person in one room, and two people in the next room, which we denote $12$.
- All three people in one room, which we denote $3$.

The dynamics of the chain are also fairly simple:

- From $111$, we can only move to $21$.  Because we only care about the *relative* positioning of the people, all three possible resulting arrangements are identical (up to rotation).
- From $21$, we can only move to $12$.
- From $12$, we move to $3$ with probability $1/3$, and to $111$ with probability $2/3$.

[image]

For any state $k$, let $t_k$ denote the expected time to reach state $3$.  Then $t_3 = 0$, and

$$
t_{111} = 1+t_{21} \\
t_{21} = 1+t_{12} \\
t_{12} = 1+\frac{2t_{111}}{3}
$$

This yields $t_{12} = 7$, $t_{21} = 8$, and in particular, $t_{111} = 9$.

With four people, we obtain the following equations:

$$
t_{1111} = 1+t_{211} \\
t_{211} = 1+\frac{3t_{121}}{4}+\frac{t_{202}}{4} \\
t_{121} = 1+\frac{3t_{112}}{4}+\frac{t_{31}}{4} \\
t_{31} = 1+\frac{3t_{22}}{4}+\frac{t_{103}}{4} \\
t_{202} = 1+t_{112} \\
t_{112} = 1+\frac{t_{1111}}{2}+\frac{t_{22}}{4}+\frac{t_{103}}{4} \\
t_{22} = 1+\frac{t_{211}}{2}+\frac{t_{13}}{2} \\
t_{103} = 1+\frac{3t_{211}}{4}+\frac{t_{13}}{4} \\
t_{13} = 1+\frac{3t_{121}}{4}
$$

When one solves this stack of equations, one obtains $t_{1111} = \frac{1042}{15} = 69\frac{7}{15}$, well in line with Remy's simulation value.

Comment: I also used the Markov chain approach, but went into rather "brute force" direction - I made a probability matrix for all 35 possible states, turned it into the fundamental matrix and obtained a probability of $69\frac{2}{3}$. I don't fully get your notation, so I cannot follow your calculations. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @yassem: Oh dear, that'll be difficult to distinguish.  I've added an example for $n = 3$; does that help?

Comment: There's not a ton of symmetry left in this reduced chain, so I might easily have made a typo entering this into my CAS.

Comment: @yassem: Well, I did discover a typo, but rather annoyingly, it did not completely resolve the difference between our solutions, but only made it even harder to distinguish.

Comment: I actually made a typo re-writting my answer, it's actually $69.4667$, not $69.6667$, so $69\frac{7}{15}$. What's you new answer?

Comment: Oh, I just saw :) Yes, I'd say that is the final answer, since both our very different methods resulted in that.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a solution but rather an empirical simulation using R. Perhaps it could useful as a check of someone's work:

```
values=c() 
for(i in c(1:(10^5))){
count=0
urn<-c("red","blue","green","yellow")
while(length(unique(urn))!=1){ #while loop ends when the urn contains 1 unique element
u=floor(runif(1,1,5)) #random integer between 1 and 4, inclusive
urn[u]<-ifelse(urn[u]=="red","blue",ifelse(urn[u]=="blue","green",
ifelse(urn[u]=="green","yellow",ifelse(urn[u]=="yellow","red"))))
#changes the value at the randomly selected index to be the newly painted ball color
count=count+1}
i=i+1
values<-c(values,count)} #adds number of iterations needed in that trial to the vector
mean(values)

[1] 69.40828
```

The expected value should come out to be in the $65-75$ range. Again, this is not in any way a solution. It will be interesting to see how it compares to the analytical solution.

Comment: I don't understand this language, it would be helpful if you use comments in your source code (I understand java).

Comment: I will add that!

Answer (score 1):

Up to a cyclic permutation of the colors there are the ten states
$$1234, \ 1123, \ 1223, \ 1233, \ 1122, \ 1133, \ 1222, 1333,\ 1112, \ 1111\ .$$
Denote by $t_\iota$ the expected number of moves to reach state $1111$ from state $\iota$. Then you have nine equations, whereby
$$t_{1233}=1+{1\over4}t_{1122}+{1\over4} t_{1333}+{1\over2}t_{1234}$$
is one example. Solving these equations gives in particular $$t_{1234}={1042\over15}\approx69.4667\ ,$$
as in Brian Tung's answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have replaced the colors with numbers $1,2,3,4$ in the following java code.
 When I ran the code I got the expected value **$70$** for 10000 iterations.
[image]

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class prob1
{
 public static void main(String args[])
{Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
int n=s.nextInt();

int m=0;
for(int i=0;i<=n-1;i++)       
 {  int A[] ={1,2,3,4}; int c=0;        
  while((A[0]!=A[1])||(A[0]!=A[2])||(A[0]!=A[3]))
 {     
       c++;
     double ran= 4*Math.random();
int r=(int) ran;

  if(A[r]==1){A[r]=2;}
  else if(A[r]==2){A[r]=3;}
  else if(A[r]==3){A[r]=4;}
  else{A[r]=1;}

System.out.print(A[0]+"-"+A[1]+"-"+A[2]+"-"+A[3]);
}
m=m+c;
}
System.out.println((double) m/n);


}
}
```

Comment: Intuitively the process should take a while. For example, if you have 3 reds and another color,  then chances are you'll select a red and the color will change. I don't know java but you might want to review it.

Comment: @Remy to calculate the expected value i just took the mean of no. of trials, maybe that doesn't give the expected value.

Comment: No that should be right. I think after you found the desired ball's index, you changed the color of more than one ball, rather than going to the next iteration in your while loop. You need if else statements.

Comment: @Remy: I think the chain of if statements needs else statements.  Otherwise, if (for instance) the $r$th ball is color $1$, then it will change color four times and return to color $1$ again, as each of the if statements is triggered in turn.  I bet every run yields four balls of color $1$.

Comment: Yeah I think so too. Shouldn't be a hard fix @ShubhashishChauhan

Comment: I just added "else" to the second, third, and fourth "if" statements, and it runs just fine.  After $40$ million runs, I get $69.467$.  I suspect the distribution has a coefficient of variation less than $1$, and if so, the standard deviation on that value should be less than $0.01$.

Comment: @BrianTung Yes i corrected it too check the update.